# XAMPP Access forbidden error

Tags: apache, hosting, xampp

I was trying to host a simple website from my home computer.I have static IP and set it from conf file but it gives access error.

Access forbidden!

New XAMPP security concept:

Access to the requested object is only available from the local network.

This setting can be configured in the file "httpd-xampp.conf".

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster. 
Error 403

As far as I can tell it manages to find the site but there is an authorization problem.What can I do to make it open to public?It's running on Windows 7.There are solutions for mostly Linux.I tried them but didn't work :-(

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (assumes Windows 7 XAMPP install):

- Open your XAMPP control panel
- On the line for Apache click on "Config"
- Click on Apache (httpd-xampp.conf)
  (Or use notepad to locate c:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf)
- Scroll to the bottom or until you see "# New XAMPP security concept"
- If you don't care about security: change "Deny from all" to "Allow from all"
- Otherwise:

  - locate the last line in the "Allow from" section: (usually 169.253.0.0./16)
  - add a new entry with your static IP address here's the tricky bit: you'll need to add "/8", "/12", or "/16" after this IP address, depending on what it is.  If it's a 192.168.x.x address, add "/16". If it's a "10.x.x.x" address add "/8".  If it's an address supplied to you by an ISP, you'll have to experiment.  The "/NNN" notation indicates the number of bits in front which represent the network portion of the address.
- Save the file
- Stop and Start Apache